# Problem with encoding

Tags: utf-8

i have written my HTML code with the meta datas of

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" 
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="NO-CACHE"
meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt"

it is in UTF-8 format but when i opened this page in IE6 browser the encoding type is western european(ISO) so it shows portuguese language as **informaÃ§Ã£o** originaly the string is **informação**

what could be the problem

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is IE6. Ask any web developer.

Anyway, you'd better concentrate on newer browser versions, there's no use wasting your time with IE6 because you won't learn anything other than that it implements its own standards, which is absolutely not useful.